# What does it mean by "PC" in this article?

Tags: protein-structure, algorithms

What does it mean by "PC" in this article?

- [a fast and efficient Cα-based method for accurately assigning protein secondary structure elements](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/24995959/)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Answer from @user438383, @matteo-ferla and @m, converted from comments [anyone, feel free to edit this answer to improve it]:*

According to the intro it means 'pseudocenter'. All measurements are relative to an assigned point because a protein doesn't have a 'centre' they assigned it as a pseudocentre.

Note that PC normally means principal component, but that does not seem to be the case here.